# Thready safety within Singleton

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, factory

I have a Singleton Factory that has final static concurrent hashmap that contains mutable objects identified by unikey key, initializing this object is "heavy" operation (as it reads xml static data) so I decided to store it with key value pair map within this factory. So far so good as I am able to cache this initialization of map and (this object) once Factory is loaded but now the problem is since this object is mutable each thread can modify its state and thus calling thread always gets state of this object from previous thread.

```
public final class SingletonWriterFactory {

    private static Map<String, WriterFormat> FORMATTER_MAP = loadMap();

    private static class Loader {
       static final SingletonWriterFactory INSTANCE = new SingletonWriterFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the single instance of this factory.
     *
     * @return The single instance of this factory
     */
    public static SingletonWriterFactory getInstance() {
       return Loader.INSTANCE;
    } 

    private static Map<String, WriterFormat> loadMap() {
     Map<String, WriterFormat> formatterMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,WriterFormat>();
     Configuration config = ConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(CONFIG_FILE);
     List<WriterFormatConfiguration> cfgs = getInstance().getWriterFormatConfigurations(config);
     WriterFormat [] formatters = getInstance().createWriterFormats(config, cfgs);
     for (int i = 0; i < formatters.length; i++) {
        String formatterId = formatters[i].getId();
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(formatterId)) {
            formatterMap.put(formatterId, formatters[i]);
        }
     }
     return formatterMap;
    }


    public synchronized WriterFormat createWriterFormat(String id) {
     if (FORMATTER_MAP != null && !FORMATTER_MAP.containsKey(id)) {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(CONFIG_FILE);
        List<WriterFormatConfiguration> cfgs = getWriterFormatConfigurations(config);
        WriterFormat[] formatters = createWriterFormats(config, cfgs);
        for (int i = 0; i < formatters.length; i++) {
            if (formatters[i].getWriterFormatConfiguration().getId().equals(id)) {
                FORMATTER_MAP.put(id, formatters[i]);
                return formatters[i];
            }
        }
     }
    return FORMATTER_MAP.get(id);
   }
}
```

Now, I have a class that tie all this together as below :

```
public class TransportDataWriter {

    public void write(Serializable messageKey, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
      Message inter = dao.findByMessageKey(messageKey);
      String mti = messageTypeResolver.determineMTI(messageKey);
      if (mti != null) {
        context = populateWriterFormatContext(inter);
        WriterFormat format = SingletonWriterFactory.getInstance().createWriterFormat(mti);
        context.setWriterFormatConfiguration(format.getWriterFormatConfiguration());
        format.format(context);
        byte[] databytes = creator.createMessage(context, format);
        outputStream.write(databytes);
      } else {
        throw CORE.getException(1601, messageKey);
      }
   }
}
```

The problem I have is that WriterFormat instance contains field values that is calculated during format method is called now every new call to write returns values from previous thread values encapsulatyed by WriterFormat, which is overwritten of course but when previous thread has more fields than then new thread that field value is also printed making "their" Message wrong for successive calls.

Edit :
I have done the following now :
1. Using apache SerializationUtils I cloned the WriterFormat underlying fields. This will make sure all thread will get clones copy of fields encapsulated by WriterFormat.
2. I have created new data type OutgoingMessage that just holds the synchronized list of MessageFields with getter/setter both synchronized.

Now my code looks like below :

```
public void write(Serializable messageKey, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
  Message inter = dao.findByMessageKey(messageKey);
  String mti = messageTypeResolver.determineMTI(messageKey);
  if (mti != null) {
    context = populateWriterFormatContext(inter);
    WriterFormat format = SingletonWriterFactory.getInstance().createWriterFormat(mti);
    context.setWriterFormatConfiguration(format.getWriterFormatConfiguration());
    OutgoingMessage m = new OutgoingMessage();        
    format.format(context,m);
    byte[] databytes = creator.createMessage(context, m);
    outputStream.write(databytes);
  } else {
    throw CORE.getException(1601, messageKey);
  }
}
```

OutgoingMessage is just holder of cloned fields as below  :

```
public final class OutgoingMessage implements Serializable {

/**
 * Thread safe collection of OutgoingMessageField field.
 */
private Collection<OutgoingMessageField> messageField =
        Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<OutgoingMessageField>());

/**
 * 
 * @param field
 */
public synchronized void setOutgoingMessageField(OutgoingMessageField field) {
    messageField.add(field);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public synchronized Collection<OutgoingMessageField> getOutgoingMessageFields() {
    return messageField;
}
}
```

So, far no race condition or multi thread issue. But I need this code to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you "cache" your `WriterFormat` instances because it is expensive to read them from the xml and you only want to do it once. Which makes sense.
But how expensive is it to "copy construct" a new `WriterFormat` from the one that has been already constructed and cached? Is `WriterFormat` your own implementation? Depending on what you want to achieve and how expensive the copy would be you can either

- Create a new copy for every thread or
- Make the related interface methods of `WriterFormat` synchronized. Better yet, provide a synchronized wrapper for it.

If copying is not a huge overhead, I would go for that, so no state is shared between threads.

Comment: Creating new copy of Writer for every thread would beat the purpose of cahing that object.  The second option seems ok to me, can I also make    
    WriterFormat format = SingletonWriterFactory.getInstance().createWriterFormat(mti);

format instance as volatile,  just thinking ?

Comment: Volatile does not affect the way methods are called or synchronized on your instance. Volatile on a reference only means that the reference (the block of memory that holds the "address" to your instance) itself is marked volatile.
Also, in your original post, you explain your motivation for caching by pointing out that reading from an XML and constructing your object from it is expensive. It may not be that expensive to simply copy your existing instance, since it does not have to be read and parsed again. Only the state has to be copied.

Comment: Since the root of your problem is that the _state_ of your instance in shared by threads, and is getting messed up by concurrent usage, making copies from each thread may not be that counter productive as it may seem.
Instead of trying to guard the state of your instance forcefully, you can drop the problem alltogether with giving your threads separate objects. As I said, if your instance is already in memory, it _may_ not be such a big deal to copy it. The main point here: _If you don't have a really good reason to share states between threads, then don't do it_.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can do that will BeanUtils from apache can help me here or any other lib to avoid writing boilerplate code.